# Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Al querer hacer un bulk desde una variable me sale estos errores:

> (0 rows affected)
> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 57
> Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 57
> The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 57
> Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Este es mi código:

```
Alter PROCEDURE SPI_Archivos    
@filePath VARCHAR(MAX)    
AS    
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE TempTableBalanza
Create Table TempTableBalanza(
Cuenta nvarchar(max),
Nombre nvarchar(max),
Monto nvarchar(max),
Fecha nvarchar(max),
Clasificación nvarchar(max)
)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT TempTableBalanza FROM ''' + @filePath + ''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR ='','', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'', Lastrow = 30000003)';
select * from TempTableBalanza
EXEC(@sql);

--EXEC SP_executesql @SQL
   END
```

Mi archivo es un *txt* delimitado por tabulaciones.

Espero que me puedan ayudar :c

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor cambia la imagen del error y agrégala como texto, las imágenes solo deben ser utilizadas solo cuando de verdad son necesarias. ;)

Comment: listo :)   ya lo actualice